# EXCEL Function to Separate Only Last 3 Values From Address With Comma Delimited

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using **Excel 2013**. I have an `excel sheet` with addresses. I want to put Post Codes, Region, and town in s separate column. The addresses are separated from the comma. Of course, I can use the `"Text to Column"` function but the issue is that there are also address that have commas within the street address.

For example:

> 201 Battle Road, st. Leonards-on-sea, East Sussex, TN37 7AJ

&

> Inside Pets At Home, unit 3, bridge of don retail park, denmore road,
> Aberdeen, Aberdeenshire, AB23 8JW

In this example, I am only interested in separating the last 3 values with a comma which is Town name, Region, and Zipcode. But the `"Text to Column"` function separates all the values which I don't want.

What's the best way to handle this so it only separates the last 3 values?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: I am using Excel 2013 @ScottCraner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel O365 you could use (using spilling behaviour):

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()>last()-3]"))
```

In other Excel versions (from Excel 2013 onwards) you could use:

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()>last()-3]"),COLUMN(A1))
```

And drag two cells to the right.

---

[image]

Comment: It worked, thank you. Can you also tell me how can I also remove those 3 values from the address? I don't need those values anymore since they are in a separate cell. @JvdV

Comment: You want to actually replace your original input in `A1`. It can be done in a seperate cell.

Comment: Yeah, so first I want to extract the last 3 values from A1 to B1, C1, D1, and then I don't want those extracted values anymore in the cell A1. So the following address (Inside Pets At Home, unit 3, bridge of don retail park, denmore road, Aberdeen, Aberdeenshire, AB23 8JW) should be (Inside Pets At Home, unit 3, bridge of don retail park, denmore road) like this in the cell A1.

Comment: That won't be possible without some extra steps. Maybe better to use something other than formulas then. VBA possibly.

Comment: Better off splitting A1 into B1 (for the left overs) C1, D1, E1 then turning around and deleting column A after a copy and paste values for columns B:E